# How to make mobs spawn where the player is at random intervals?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hello I'm trying to make a plugin/mod where mobs(1 - 31) randomly spawn at the players coords, but I'm very new to coding in Minecraft so any help will be appreciated.

I'm playing on 1.18

Comment: Some more info would be helpful, how far have you got? What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: It sounds like you are unaware of the difference between plugins and mods. You also have included the [minecraft-commands] tag, which suggests you are looking for a solution related to datapacks. These 3 things (datapacks, plugins, mods) are very different things, so make sure you understand what they are.

Comment: A quick and dirty way I know is to have a chicken run over some pressure plates, as seen [here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Randomizers#Mob_randomizer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Psuedo Random**, it is not entirely random but it's fast enough to be "*random*".
To do ***Pseudo Random*** you can add a dummy scoreboard to yourself

```
/scoreboard objectives add psuedoRandom dummy
```

Then you can create a repeating command block that increments it or changes it to a random one

```
/scoreboard players add @s psuedoRandom 1
```

Then add a repeating command block that resets it everytime it goes to the max limit

```
/execute if score @s pseudoRandom matches 100.. run scoreboard players reset psuedoRandom
```

Then you can add a repeating command block that checks if the psuedo random is at a specific number then summon depending on what mob you choose

```
/execute if score @s pseudoRandom matches 69 run summon tnt ~ ~1 ~
```